# What is the difference between zero background radiation and field background radiation in Nuclear Physics measurements?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, measurements, nuclear-engineering

Can someone please explain the difference between these two terms (Zero Background Radiation and Field Background Radiation) used in radiometric prospecting measurements?

Comment: Do you mean Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation?

Comment: Can you link to texts which use these terms in the manner you're thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the abstract of this article [Measurements of environmental background radiation at location of coal-fired power plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation) (PubMed, 2004)  the terms are used in context.

**"Zero background radiation"** - is the natural expected radiation measured far away of the specific pollutant site - the coal mine. It is a control or reference value in the study.

**"[Background radiation field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation)"** is the **effective ambient radiation**

> Record radiation levels were found in a house where the effective dose
>   due to **ambient radiation fields** was 131 mSv/a,

in the same abstract:

> This investigation has been primarily done in order to check the
>   impact of coal-fired power plants on the **background radiation level** in
>   its vicinity